# Connectedness of an Image

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing

Given the sets $S_1 = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}; Im(z) > 1 \}$, $S_2 = \{z \in \mathbb{C}; Im(z) < -2\}$, is the image of $S_1 \bigcup S_2$ connected (path connected) under the map $w = z^2$?

My problem with questions like this is that I know the definitions, it just seems unclear on how to apply them to a proof. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Write down a formula parametrizing the set of points on the boundary of $S_1$; then apply the map $z\mapsto z^2$ to it. The result will be a parametrization of the boundary of $\text{Im}(S_1)$; using this, you should be able to draw a picture, shading $\text{Im}(S_1)$ (If it is unclear which side of the boundary to shade, you can always pick one point of $S_1$ and see which side it is mapped to.) Then do the same thing with $S_2$, and use the fact that $\text{Im}(S_1 \cup S_2) = \text{Im}(S_1)\cup\text{Im}(S_2)$.